# Image do not display in react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

I was using react-native@0.48.2 and react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.13 as navigator module to develope my android app.When I switch one page to another one for about 20-30 times, some images just don't display, what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is react-native itself!

Comment: How can I revolve this problem?